# DTS: Removing node to free the pins

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hardware, device-tree

I need to use two pins that are taking by a node labeled as fec2. I have tried removing it with `/delete-node/ &fec2` but that gives me a compile error saying that there is no such node or label.

I want to remove fec2 and move it's mdio to fec1 so that my ethernet connection still functions. But when I try just that (see example below) eth0 won't get an IP address.

imx6ul.dtsi contains the following:

```
/ {
    soc {
        /* Some soc configs */

        aips1: aips-bus@02000000 {
            /* aips configs */

            fec2: ethernet@020b4000 {
                compatible = "fsl,imx6ul-fec", "fsl,imx6q-fec";
                reg = <0x020b4000 0x4000>;
                interrupts = <GIC_SPI 120 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>,
                         <GIC_SPI 121 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
                clocks = <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET>,
                     <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET_AHB>,
                     <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET_PTP>,
                     <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET2_REF_125M>,
                     <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET2_REF_125M>;
                clock-names = "ipg", "ahb", "ptp",
                          "enet_clk_ref", "enet_out";
                stop-mode = <&gpr 0x10 4>;
                fsl,num-tx-queues=<1>;
                fsl,num-rx-queues=<1>;
                fsl,magic-packet;
                fsl,wakeup_irq = <0>;
                status = "disabled";
            };
        };

        aips2: aips-bus@02100000 {
            /* aips configs */

            fec1: ethernet@02188000 {
                compatible = "fsl,imx6ul-fec", "fsl,imx6q-fec";
                reg = <0x02188000 0x4000>;
                interrupts = <GIC_SPI 118 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>,
                         <GIC_SPI 119 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
                clocks = <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET>,
                     <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET_AHB>,
                     <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET_PTP>,
                     <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET_REF>,
                     <&clks IMX6UL_CLK_ENET_REF>;
                clock-names = "ipg", "ahb", "ptp",
                          "enet_clk_ref", "enet_out";
                stop-mode = <&gpr 0x10 3>;
                fsl,num-tx-queues=<1>;
                fsl,num-rx-queues=<1>;
                fsl,magic-packet;
                fsl,wakeup_irq = <0>;
                status = "disabled";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

imx6ul-imx6ull-common.dtsi contains the following overwrite:

```
&fec1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_enet1>;
    phy-mode = "rmii";
    phy-reset-gpios=<&gpio5 0 1>;
    phy-reset-duration=<100>;
    phy-reset-on-resume;
    phy-handle = <&ethphy0>;
    status = "okay";
};

&fec2 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_enet2>;
    phy-mode = "rmii";
    phy-handle = <&ethphy1>;
    phy-reset-gpios=<&gpio1 10 1>;
    phy-reset-duration=<100>;
    phy-reset-on-resume;
    status = "okay";
    mdio {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        ethphy0: ethernet-phy@1 {
            compatible = "ethernet-phy-ieee802.3-c22";
            micrel,rmii-reference-clock-select-25-mhz;
            clocks = <&rmii_ref_clk>;
            clock-names = "rmii-ref";
            reg = <1>;
        };

        ethphy1: ethernet-phy@3 {
            compatible = "ethernet-phy-ieee802.3-c22";
            micrel,rmii-reference-clock-select-25-mhz;
            clocks = <&rmii_ref_clk>;
            clock-names = "rmii-ref";
            reg = <3>;
        };
    };
};
```

And my device.dts contains the following:

```
#include "imx6ul.dtsi"
#include "imx6ul-imx6ull-var-dart-common.dtsi"

/* Disable the second ethernet port and remove the mdio for use in fec1 */
&fec2 {
    status = "disabled";
    /delete-node/ mdio;
};

/* Add the mdio to the fec1 interface */
&fec1 {
    mdio {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        ethphy0: ethernet-phy@1 {
            compatible = "ethernet-phy-ieee802.3-c22";
            micrel,rmii-reference-clock-select-25-mhz;
            clocks = <&rmii_ref_clk>;
            clock-names = "rmii-ref";
            reg = <1>;
        };

        ethphy1: ethernet-phy@3 {
            compatible = "ethernet-phy-ieee802.3-c22";
            micrel,rmii-reference-clock-select-25-mhz;
            clocks = <&rmii_ref_clk>;
            clock-names = "rmii-ref";
            reg = <3>;
        };
    };
};
```

I expect my ethernet connection to still work and fec2 to be deleted.

Comment: When fec2 has status `disabled`, the pinctrl subsystem will not assign any pins for that device.  You can confirm that by enabling debug for the pinctrl subsystem, e.g. CONFIG_DEBUG_PINCTRL.

Comment: @sawdust would the mdio in fec2 still be available for fec1?

Comment: When fec2 has status `disabled`,  you are specifying that the board does not have or use the device that the node describes.  So nothing in the fec2 node, including the mdio child-node, should have meaning or be allocated.

Comment: So the solution would be to set fec2 to disabled, remove the mdio node with `/delete-node/` and then add mdio to fec1?

Comment: Given what you have posted, try removing the `/delete-node/ mdio;` from the **device.dts** file.